# Java Mail API: Convert Message to String?

Tags: java, regex, string, jakarta-mail

I am using the following code to successfully retrieve messages from my Gmail account.

```
// Import Statements 

    public class ConfirmEmail {

    WebDriver driver;
    Folder inbox;

    String gmailID = "xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
    String gmailPass = "xxxxxxxx";
    String storeMessage;

    public ConfirmEmail()
    {

    }

    public void MailReader() {
        System.out.println("Inside MailReader()...");
        final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";

        /* Set the mail properties */

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        // Set manual Properties
        props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
        props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.pop3.port", "995");
        props.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", "995");
        props.put("mail.pop3.host", "pop.gmail.com");

        try

        {

            /* Create the session and get the store for read the mail. */

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(
                    System.getProperties(), null);

            Store store = session.getStore("pop3");

            store.connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, gmailID,
                    gmailPass);

            /* Mention the folder name which you want to read. */

            // inbox = store.getDefaultFolder();
            // inbox = inbox.getFolder("INBOX");
            inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");

            /* Open the inbox using store. */

            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            /* Get the messages which is unread in the Inbox */

            Message messages[] = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(
                    Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));
            System.out.println("No. of Unread Messages : " + messages.length);

            /* Use a suitable FetchProfile */
            FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
            fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);

            fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.CONTENT_INFO);

            inbox.fetch(messages, fp);

            try

            {

                printAllMessages(messages);

                inbox.close(true);
                store.close();

            }

            catch (Exception ex)

            {
                System.out.println("Exception arise at the time of read mail");

                ex.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

        catch (MessagingException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception while connecting to server: "
                    + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(2);
        }

    }

    public void printAllMessages(Message[] msgs) throws Exception
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++)
        {

            System.out.println("MESSAGE #" + (i + 1) + ":");

            printEnvelope(msgs[i]);
        }

    }

    public void printEnvelope(Message message) throws Exception

    {

        Address[] a;

        // FROM

        if ((a = message.getFrom()) != null) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                System.out.println("FROM: " + a[j].toString());
            }
        }
        // TO
        if ((a = message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO)) != null) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                System.out.println("TO: " + a[j].toString());
            }
        }
        String subject = message.getSubject();

        Date receivedDate = message.getReceivedDate();
        Date sentDate = message.getSentDate(); // receivedDate is returning
                                                // null. So used getSentDate()

        String content = message.getContent().toString();
        System.out.println("Subject : " + subject);
        if (receivedDate != null) {
            System.out.println("Received Date : " + receivedDate.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("Sent Date : " + sentDate.toString());
        System.out.println("Content : " + content);

        getContent(message);

    }





    public void getContent(Message msg)

    {
        try {
            String contentType = msg.getContentType();
            System.out.println("Content Type : " + contentType);
            Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
            int count = mp.getCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                dumpPart(mp.getBodyPart(i));
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception arise at get Content");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void dumpPart(Part p) throws Exception {
        // Dump input stream ..
        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        // If "is" is not already buffered, wrap a BufferedInputStream
        // around it.
        if (!(is instanceof BufferedInputStream)) {
            is = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        }
        int c;
        System.out.println("Message : ");
        while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.write(c);


        }
    }



}
```

With this code I am successfully able to print messages to console. Works flawlessly 100% of the time.

However, I need to store the "bodyPart" (i.e, the actual message or body of message) in a String so I could search the String using Regex. I need to extract links begining with http.

How can I convert the message to a string?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking (because you said you already print out your Messages ... so when you print them, why can't you store them in a String?)

if you realy just want the bodyPart stored in a String variable:

```
Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);
String content = bp.getContent().toString();
```

Comment: It worked and gave me complete body content as a string. But in my mail there is URL. I want that URL as it is. but above code has given me href. How can I get only URL?